# Prevent Typo3 broken image url error

Tags: typo3, fluid, fluid-images

In my Typo3 extension I'm showing a lot of images with fluid, an list view of products. Only if for some reason one image is missing on my server, Typo3 generates an full screen error so the complete website is then not working.

I my opinion there are three way to prevent it:

1) Configure Typo3 so it is ignoring broken image url's. Does anyone know if this is possible?

2) Let Fluid check if the image exists before it is generated. Don't know if this is possible?

3) Use the controller to check if the image exists before it is send to the frond-end. Only due to the manny images it uses a lot of processing.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer the use of the media exists viewhelper from the [VHS Viewhelper](https://github.com/FluidTYPO3/vhs) package. After installing and activating the extension it should look like this screenshot in your TYPO3 extension manager. [image: Screenshot]

This example iterates through a array of products, that have a public picture property holding the filename of it's picture.

```
{namespace v=FluidTYPO3\Vhs\ViewHelpers}

<f:for each="{products}" as="product">
    <v:media.exists file="fileadmin/products/{product.picture}">
        <f:then>
            <f:image src="fileadmin/products/{product.picture}" />
        </f:then>
        <f:else>
            <f:image src="fileadmin/noImageFound.jpg" />
        </f:else>
    </v:media.exists>
</f:for>
```

Comment: I have added it exactly as in your example but I'm still getting the same error?

Comment: I think you've already installed the VHS Viewhelpers in your TYPO3 project. Have you activated the extension in the extension manager?

Comment: I still getting the Typo3 error and I have installed the VHS extension